# Не работает INSERT INTO mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['auth_admin'] == "yes_auth")
    {


           if (isset($_GET["logout"]))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['auth_admin']);
            header("Location: login.php");
        }

      $_SESSION['urlpage'] = "<a href='index.php' >Главная</a> \ <a href='tovar.php' >Товары</a> \ <a>Добавление товара</a>";

   ///15строка////   include("include/db_connect.php");
      include("functions.php"); 

        if ($_POST["submit_add"])
        {
     if ($_SESSION['add_tovar'] == '1')
     {

          $error = array();

        // Проверка полей

           if (!$_POST["form_title"])
          {
             $error[] = "Укажите название товара";
          }

           if (!$_POST["form_price"])
          {
             $error[] = "Укажите цену";
          }

           if (!$_POST["form_category"])
          {
             $error[] = "Укажите категорию";         
          }else
          {
            $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM category1 WHERE id='{$_POST["form_category"]}'");
            var_dump(mysqli_error($link));
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $selecttovar = $row["tovar"];

          }

     // Проверка чекбоксов

           if ($_POST["chk_visible"])
           {
              $chk_visible = "1";
           }else { $chk_visible = "0"; }


           if (count($error))
           {           
                $_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-error'>".implode('<br />',$error)."</p>";

           }else
           {

                        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table_product(title,price,tovar,seo_wordls,seo_description,mini_description,description,mini_features,features,visible,type_tovara,tovar_id)
                            VALUES(                     
                                '".$_POST["form_title"]."',
                                '".$_POST["form_price"]."',
                                '".$selecttovar."',
                                '".$_POST["form_seo_worlds"]."',
                                '".$_POST["form_seo_description"]."',
                                '".$_POST["txt1"]."',
                                '".$_POST["txt2"]."',
                                '".$_POST["txt3"]."',
                                '".$_POST["txt4"]."',
                                '".$chk_visible."',
                                '".$_POST["form_type"]."',
                                '".$_POST["form_category"]."'                               
                            )");


          $_SESSION['message'] = "<p id='form-success'>Товар успешно добавлен!</p>";
          $id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

           if (empty($_POST["upload_image"]))
          {        
          include("actions/upload-image.php");
          unset($_POST["upload_image"]);           
          } 

           if (empty($_POST["galleryimg"]))
          {        
          include("actions/upload-gallery.php"); 
          unset($_POST["galleryimg"]);                 
          }
    }


     }else
     {
       $msgerror = 'У вас нет прав на добавление товаров!'; 
     }            
    }
```

Comment: Можно подробности? У вас ошибка в запросе? У вас в `$_POST` приходит недостаточно данных?

Comment: Никаких ошибок не замечено,просто бд не пополняется новыми данными.Просто выводится "Товар успешно добавлен!" и все

Comment: Может в запросе ошибки в синтаксисе?

Comment: Ну а почему вы не проверяете результат функции `mysqli_query`?

Comment: Конечно не будет ошибок. Особенно если их не проверять. `mysqli_query` это **функция**, которая возвращает результат.

Comment: Я вам даже больше скажу, почему вы не используете подготовленные запросы? Вас проблема SQL-инъекций ни разу не беспокоит? А стоило бы

Comment: string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table_product'(title,price,tovar,seo_wordls,seo_description,mini_description,de' at line 1"

Comment: Все же синтаксисом траблы,не подскажите как правильно?Или мануал подскажите,где точно смогу найти,пожалуйста

Comment: имя таблицы не пишется в апострофах, максимум в обратных апострофах ``

Comment: Уже понял,только вот теперь он почему-то ругается за файл подключения к бд(смотрите правку)

Comment: string(148) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 15

Comment: Не стал ничего из кода добавлять,пшто не уверен что вам что-то даст это "include("include/db_connect.php");"
Раньше с ним проблем не было

Comment: Надо наверно угадать где 15 строка?

Comment: посмотрите,пожалуйста,я отметил 15 строку